# The goal is for the latest version, All results must be 'OK' or All must be 'Waiting' in SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE ssssql (
  id_no int(3) ,
  pid varchar(3) ,
  version int(1) ,
  status varchar(7) 
);

INSERT INTO ssssql (id_no, pid, version, status) VALUES
(123, 'P08', 1, 'VOID'),
(124, 'P08', 1, 'VOID'),
(125, 'P08', 2, 'Waiting'),
(126, 'P08', 2, 'Waiting'),
(127, 'P08', 2, 'VOID'),
(128, 'P08', 2, 'OK'),
(129, 'P08', 2, 'OK'),
(130, 'P08', 2, 'OK'),
(131, 'P08', 2, 'Waiting'),
(132, 'P08', 2, 'OK'),
(133, 'P08', 1, 'VOID'),
(134, 'P08', 1, 'VOID'),
(135, 'P08', 2, 'Waiting')
(136, 'P08', 3, 'OK')
(137, 'P08', 3, 'OK')
(138, 'P08', 3, 'OK');
```

The goal is for the latest version, All results must be 'OK' or All must be 'Waiting'

here latest version = 2

If all status ='OK' OR all status = 'Waiting' For the version 2. Then extract the records, otherwise no output.

See the version = 3. all status = 'OK' so for version 3. it must shows all records because all status = 'OK'

I want to write SQL query for this.

Expected output:

```
(136, 'P08', 3, 'OK')
(137, 'P08', 3, 'OK')
(138, 'P08', 3, 'OK')
```

Because all the status  'OK' for latest version =3

If all were 'Waiting' rather than 'OK' For 3, then output should also come because all status value are same ('Waiting')

Comment: Please clarify what you've tried to solve this already?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here. This is clearly, however, *not* SQL Server as the `imt` type doesn't have a precision on T-SQL. This also is therey very unlikely to be related to (SQL Server's) Query Store feature. I suspect this is therefore MySQL related, but please correct your tags.

Comment: Provide desired output for shown source data.

Comment: I realize your question is quite unclear.  What do you mean by "latest version".  Please show the results you want.

Comment: The latest version is 2. 

for the version 2

if all status values are 'OK' OR all 'Waiting' Then it must shows result. Otherwise no output.

Comment: @NaveedAhmad you may find it helpful to read [**How to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then to **edit** your question so we can understand what you are trying to achieve, what you've done and why it's failed so far. Thank you.

Comment: Version 2 is the "latest", because it's in the row with the highest ID? Or because 2 > 1? And you don't want to show anything, because it has rows with both statuses?

Comment: The goal is to extract all records for version = 2 ONLY if all status = 'OK' OR all status = 'Waiting' ...... Like for all values of status ='OK' OR 'Waiting' for the version = 2 then output shows all records ONLY.

Comment: Okay. Then select the latest version first. You can do this, yes? Then select the minimum and maximum status for this version. Can you do this? Check whther both are OK or both are Waiting or neither. If both are OK or Waiting, select the rows. Try this and come back if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thorsten, Thank you for response. I know how to get the maximum value for the version. After that I have to check whether all status for the latest version are 'OK' if all OK then extract all records. If all 'Waiting'  then extract the records. Otherwise if for latest version, the status is mix of 'OK', 'Waiting' 'VOID' then NO OUTPUT. I hope this clarify all things.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get the rows matching the latest version.

```
SELECT *

FROM ssssql

WHERE version = (
    SELECT max(version) FROM ssssql
)
```

You'll also probably want some filtering on status, but it's not clear what you want from the example.

Comment: Thank you for response. This is ok.  After that I have to check whether all status for the latest version are 'OK' if all OK then extract all records. If all 'Waiting' then extract the records. Otherwise if for latest version, the status is mix of 'OK', 'Waiting' 'VOID' then NO OUTPUT. I hope this clarify all things

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad Maybe you can combine my answer with OwlsSleeping's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
select a.*
from   ssssql a
       inner join
       (select version,
               count(status) CntAll,
               count(case when status = 'OK' then 1 end) CntOk,
               count(case when status = 'Waiting' then 1 end) CntWaiting
        from   ssssql
        group by version
       ) b
       on a.version = b.version
where  b.CntAll = b.CntOk or b.CntAll = b.CntWaiting
```

Result:

```
id_no   pid version status
136 P08 3   OK
137 P08 3   OK
138 P08 3   OK
```

Demo(SQL Server): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca83cad84e61c6e66d7297b77456d304

Comment: You are really a GEM. Thank you. You understand the problem very well. I got what I want. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

1. Get the highest version.
2. Select that version's rows.
3. Aggregate these rows to see whether there is just one status and it's equal to 'OK' or 'Waiting'.
4. In case the version is okay, select all its rows.

The query:

```
with pid_rows as (select * from ssssql where pid = 'P08')
select *
from pid_rows
where version =
(
  select version
  from pid_rows
  where version = (select max(version) from pid_rows)
  group by version
  having count(status) = count(*) -- no nulls
     and count(distinct status) = 1 -- only one status
     and max(status) in ('OK', 'Waiting') -- the one status is a desired one
)
order by id_no;
```